# append UI element only once and avoiding event propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with my ui element (icon) with is a holder for draggable() function. the icon should append on click only once. The problem with my code is that when I am clicking on the icon it runs the code again and appending the next icon.

How avoid the event propagation in this case.Is there a better way to use the one() function here.
my code:

HTML structure:

```
<div class="editor">
  <h1>Title</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <img src="">
</div>

<div class="editor">
  <h1>Title</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <img src="">
</div>


<div class="editor">
  <h1>Title</h2>
  <p>paragraph</p>
  <img src="">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.editor *', function(event) {      
        $(this).resizable();
        $(this).draggable({ handle: ".editor-move" }); 
        $(this).one($(this).append("<i class='icon-move editor-move'></i>")); 
        return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make sure that the current target of the event is not the icon-move element, if so then exit.

```
if ($(event.target).hasClass("icon-move"))
    return false;
```

Secondly, check whether the icon has been added already on subsequent clicks to avoid added multiple icons for the same element.

```
if($(".icon-move",this).length==0)
    $(this).append("<i class='icon-move editor-move'></i>");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8NBQ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.editor *', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();      
        $(this).resizable();
        $(this).draggable({ handle: ".editor-move" }); 
        $(this).one($(this).append("<i class='icon-move editor-move'></i>")); 
        return false;
   });
```

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working, it is also creating error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'push'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).one('click', '.editor *', function(event) {      
    $(this).resizable();
    $(this).draggable({ handle: ".editor-move" }); 
    $(this).append("<i class='icon-move editor-move'></i>"); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This code will work only for the first editor, we cannot repeat this action on next one, after the function is run once.

Comment: @lipenco whether the elements are created dynamically

Comment: @lipenco also whether the elements within `editor` are draggable and resizable independently

Comment: yes, elements within editor are draggable and resizable independently

Comment: @lipenco also why is the the draggable and resizable features enabled within the click event not in page load